# Can I add a tag to a question?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I would like to add a tag to a question posted by someone else. 
How can I do so?

It is not necessarily a new tag that I want to add.

Comment: On main sites by suggesting an edit, or are you talking about on meta sites where you can't do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the tag exists you can just suggest an edit.

Make sure that you fix any other issues with the post at the same time to increase the likelihood of the edit being accepted.